2X has same distribution as sum of two iid copies of X under smooth transformation
Suppose $f:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow [0,+\infty)$ is a given strictly increasing smooth function starting from $f(0)=0$. I want to figure out under what conditions with respect to $f$ can we find nondegenerate distribution $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $f(2X)\stackrel{d}{=}f(X)+f(Y)$, where $X,Y\stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim}F$. I can only think about cases where the result cannot hold. When $f$ is convex (e.g., $f(t)=t^k,k\geq 1$), $\mathbb{E}(f(2X))\geq \mathbb{E}(2f(X))=\mathbb{E}X+\mathbb{E}Y$. The equality case implies that $f$ is linear on the support of distribution $F$. Hence $f(2X)$ and $f(X)+f(Y)$ cannot have the same distribution if $F$ is nondegenerated. Can anyone think of some idea on that?

If ${X,Y}$ is i.i.d. Cauchy then $2X$ and $X+Y$ both have the same characteristic function $e^{-2|t|}$, so they have the same distribution. There are also other infinitely divisible distributions with this property.

I want to assume that every moment of distribution $F$ exists.
